# English translation of hadran alach?

Tags: talmud-gemara, english, siyum

Hi does anyone have an English translation of the prayers at a siyum of a tractate of gemara that's translated to English? I heard there was one in the back of Artscroll gemaras but I looked in the back of the one I have and all it had was the first line.

Comment: Also see https://ohr.edu/explore/daf_yomi/8106

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a translation on Sefaria: https://www.sefaria.org/Hadran.1?lang=bi